# reducing an array into another array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade, reduce

Inside a laravel blade template, I am trying to reduce an array like this:

`$longList = [['box' => 1, 'kg' => 2], ['box' => 2, 'kg' => 2], ['box' => 3, 'kg' => 3]];`

into something like this:
`$reducedList = [['count' => 2, 'kg' => 2], ['count' => 1, 'kg' => 3]];`

This is what I have so far:

```
@php
          $variableWeights = isset($sale->variable_weight_json) ? collect(json_decode($sale->variable_weight_json, true)) : null;
          $groups = array();

          if (isset($variableWeights)) {
            $groups = $variableWeights->reduce(function($carry, $item) {
              $index = array_search($item['kg'], array_column($carry, 'weight'));
              if (isset($index)) {
                $existing = $carry[$index];
                array_splice($carry, $index, 1, [
                  'count' => $existing['count'] + 1,
                  'weight' => $item['kg']
                ]);
              } else {
                array_push($carry, [
                  'count' => 1,
                  'weight' => $item['kg'],
                ]);
              }
              return $carry;
            }, array());
          }
        @endphp
```

But it is giving me the error Undefined offset: 0

I am new to php. How should the code be corrected or is there a better approach to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you reduce it to something simpler like this

`$reducedList = [2 => 2, 3 => 1]`

where the weight is the index and the value is the count.

```php
$reducedList = [];
foreach ($longList as $box) {
    if (isset($reducedList[$box['kg']]) {
        $reducedList[$box['kg']]++;
    } else {
        $reducedList[$box['kg']] = 1;
    }
}
```

This way you avoid complexity but you still get the same amount of information.

Answer (score 1):

don't use `isset()` function. it checks only variable existing. use `empty()` or other condition, it will check variable existing and value. try this.

```
@php
          $variableWeights = isset($sale->variable_weight_json) ? collect(json_decode($sale->variable_weight_json, true)) : null;
          $groups = array();

          if ($variableWeights->isNotEmpty()) {
            $groups = $variableWeights->reduce(function($carry, $item) {
              $index = array_search($item['kg'], array_column($carry, 'weight'));
              if ($index != false ) {
                $existing = $carry[$index]?: false;
                if ($existing) {
                   array_splice($carry, $index, 1, [
                     'count' => $existing['count'] + 1,
                     'weight' => $item['kg']
                   ]);
                }
              } else {
                array_push($carry, [
                  'count' => 1,
                  'weight' => $item['kg'],
                ]);
              }
              return $carry;
            }, array());
          }
        @endphp
```

Comment: $index can have the value `0` and be valid. isset() or empty wont change much.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can achieve it with code like:

```
$longList = [['box' => 1, 'kg' => 2], ['box' => 2, 'kg' => 2], ['box' => 3, 'kg' => 3]];

$reducedList = array_values(array_reduce(
    $longList,
    function($carry, $item) {
        if (isset($carry[$item['kg']])) {
            ++$carry[$item['kg']]['count'];
        } else {
            $carry[$item['kg']] = ['count' => 1, 'kg' => $item['kg']];
        }

        return $carry;
    },
    []
));

print_r($reducedList);
```

Here is a [working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6f0501e8b9e955a9f59091d9fe4eab527418fc8).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sexy [`countBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#available-methods) method (combined with the famous [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-map) one) of the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/collections) class.

Try this:

```
$longList = [['box' => 1, 'kg' => 2], ['box' => 2, 'kg' => 2], ['box' => 3, 'kg' => 3]];

$shortList = collect($longList)
    ->countBy('kg')
    ->map(function ($count, $kg) {
        return [
            'kg' => $kg, 
            'count' => $count,
        ];
    });
```

With that, you'll get this:

```
dd($shortList);
```

> ```
> => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3380
>      all: [
>        2 => [
>          "kg" => 2,
>          "count" => 2,
>        ],
>        3 => [
>          "kg" => 3,
>          "count" => 1,
>        ],
>      ],
>    }
> ```

Here you have a [working demo](https://web.tinkerwell.app/#/snippets/204dad97-018c-4824-a7a3-16a557d59e84).

Answer (score 0):

`isset` checks if variable is set (i.e it exists and not NULL). As I (and core developers) can hardly imagine in which cases `array_search` can return `NULL`, there's a [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) which says:

> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, **FALSE** otherwise.

So, you need to check if `$index` is not **`false`**:

```
$index = array_search($item['kg'], array_column($carry, 'weight'));
// Note that I use `!==` because using `!=` will convert 
// `0` index to false, which is not correct in your case
if (false !== $index) {
```